# jquery - limiting toggleClass to 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mytable td').click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('newclass');

            });
        });
    </script>
```

This function changes the class of the selected column in my table. It works fine.

However it should not allow more than 2 columns being selected at once (by selected I mean the column having the new class toggled - newclass). So it simply should not react if other columns are clicked.

How would I do this? I could count how many columns currently use newclass and if it's 2 then cancel the function. I'm not sure how to count them or if this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's one way to ensure no more than 2

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LmDy/1/)

```
$('#mytable td').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // toggle 'on' if
    // 1. it doesn't already have the class and
    // 2. and there are less than two set to .newclass
    // toggle 'off' if
    // 1. it already has the class and
    // 2. and there are less than two set to .newclass
    $this.toggleClass('newclass', 
        !$this.hasClass('newclass') && 
        $('#mytable .newclass').length < 2);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The [size()](http://api.jquery.com/size/) method shows you how many other elements match that selector, so you can test against that before applying toggleClass():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mytable td').click(function () {
           if ($("#mytable td.newclass").size() < 2) 
           { 
               $(this).toggleClass('newclass');
           }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: use `.length` instead, it does the same as `.size()` ... per jQuery documentation `.length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.`

Comment: Probably better to use `.length` over `.size()` as `.size()` has " the overhead of a function call", according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [length](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp) property like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mytable td').click(function () {
            if ($('#mytable td.newclass').length < 2)){                
                $(this).toggleClass('newclass');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Length isn't a method, you're missing quote and your selectors are inefficient. -1

Comment: @minitech Was editing the post and the selectors are based on the OP. Really -1?

Comment: The selector inefficiency I'm talking about is selecting multiple times instead of caching the result of at least one selection. And now that the quotes and indentation are good I'll remove the -1. That's what it's for. Yeesh.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mytable td').click(function () {
            if(!$(this).hasClass('newClass')){
                if($("td.newClass").size() < 2){
                    $(this).toggleClass('newclass');
                }
            }
            else {
                 $(this).toggleClass('newclass');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```